# Need help in writing EICAR content in a utf8 file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, utf-8

Basically I have file in my Windows machine of UTF8 code. Similar to this path directory and file "G:\这是一\个令人沮". And I am trying to write EICAR string (`X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*`) to the file using PowerShell.

For regular file path it is being done like following:

```
#Base64 of Eicar string
[string] $EncodedEicar = 'WDVPIVAlQEFQWzRcUFpYNTQoUF4pN0NDKTd9JEVJQ0FSLVNUQU5EQVJELUFOVElWSVJVUy1URVNULUZJTEUhJEgrSCo='

if (!(Test-Path -Path $FilePath)) {
    try {
        [byte[]] $EicarBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncodedEicar)
        [string] $Eicar = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($EicarBytes)
        Set-Content -Value $Eicar -Encoding ascii -Path $FilePath -Force
    }
```

Tried the following suggestions didnt help :(

```
Executed powershell.exe "& {Import-Module C:\PROGRA~1\WindowsPowershell\Modules\new_eicar.psm1 -Force -DisableNameChecking ;New-Eicar -Path 'N:\这是一\个令人沮' -FileName 'eicar.com'; if ($?) {exit 0} else {exit 1}}". Result: {'status': 1, 'stderr': '', 'stdout': 'New-Eicar : Cannot validate argument on parameter \'Path\'. The "Test-Path $_ \r\n-PathType \'Container\'" validation script for the argument with value \r\n"N:\\\x8a\xa8T\x91~_\x84,?\\\x84,\xa6\x84\xaf\x0f\x84\xa7\xa7\x91\xfdr" did not return a result of True. Determine why the \r\nvalidation script failed, and then try the command again.\r\nAt line:1 char:116\r\n+ ... ew-Eicar -Path \'N:\\\x8a\xa8T\x91~_\x84,?\\\x84,\xa6\x84\xaf\x0f\x84\xa7\xa7\x91\xfdr\' -FileName \'eicar.com\'; if \r\n($?) {exit  ...\r\n+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Eicar], ParameterBindingVa \r\n   lidationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-Eicar\r\n \r\n'}
2017-08-30 23:31:12 DEBUG ssh.py:228 (TB) 10.5.22.4>> 'powershell.exe "& {Import-Module C:\PROGRA~1\WindowsPowershell\Modules\new_eicar.psm1 -Force -DisableNameChecking ;New-Eicar -Path 'N:\这是一\个令人沮' -FileName 'eicar.com'; if ($?) {exit 0} else {exit 1}}"', timeout: 300
2017-08-30 23:31:13 DEBUG ssh.py:306 (TB) 10.5.22.4<< '{
  status: 1,
  stderr: ,
  stdout: New-Eicar : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The "Test-Path $_
-PathType 'Container'" validation script for the argument with value
"N:\T~_,?\,r" did not return a result of True. Determine why the
validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:116
+ ... ew-Eicar -Path 'N:\T~_,?\,r' -FileName 'eicar.com'; if
($?) {exit  ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Eicar], ParameterBindingVa
   lidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-Eicar

}'
```

Comment: `Set-Content -Encoding utf8`?

Comment: Why using re-encode with binary data? Also with EICAR, UTF8===ASCII. Should with without playing with `GetString` etc. I wonder if you'd write value of "a" into that file and it'd succeed. Most likely you get antivirus intercepting your code writing a "virus" and you get set-content error. Please provide what error you get.